# represent Memory Stream as a physical file

Tags: c#, api, filesystems, memorystream

I've ran into a bit of a stupid problem today:

In my project I have to use a library (that I can't replace), he problem is that I'm using `MemoryStream` instead of frequently saving to the HDD (because there are many files, and they are small in size, so it's perfect for `MemoryStream`). The problem is that the library API is built around filesystem access - and one of the functions accepts only direct path to file.

How can I still send a string (path) to the method, which makes a new `FileStream` without actually touch the hard-drive?

For example "\MEMORY\myfile.bin"?

Comment: If the files are small in size, just use a FileStream.  The OS file system is likely to cache the file contents in RAM.  If you are worried about the performance of writing thousands of these from a single thread, then try using the asynchronous `BeginWrite` operations provided by FileStream.

Comment: Callback file system can be used here: http://www.eldos.com/cbfs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well - that's thought.
Basically, you have three possible solutions:

1. You can use a reflector to modify the library given.
2. You can *inspect* the appropriate method, and then, by using some reflection magic you *might* be able to modify the object at runtime (very un-recommended)
3. You can play around with system calls and API - and by going into low-level ring0 assembly modify `kernal.dll` to referrer I/O queries from your path to the memory. (maybe that's possible without ring0 access - I am not sure).

Obviously, the most recommended is to use a reflector to modify the library given. otherwise, I can't see a solution for you.

In respond to the first comment, you can:
 *use RAMDrive (a program which allocates small chunks of the system memory and show it as partition)*

Comment: Seeing that .NET does not provide such an option (whats so hard to implement MS?) i decided to use RAMDrive (program, that allocates small chunk of the system memory and show it as partition).

Comment: I was not aware of such program. That's a fair solution.

Comment: I was actually going to suggest that, but it seemed like a kludgy thing to do. (the RAMDrive)

Answer (score 1):

If the file must exist on the disk (and only disk paths are accepted), then the main option is a virtual filesystem which lets you expose custom data as a filesystem. There exist several options, such as now-dead Dokan, our Solid File System OS Edition and Callback File System (see description of our [Virtual Storage](http://www.eldos.com/virtual-storage/) product line) and maybe Pismo File Mount would work (never looked at it closely).

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on how the library is constructed.

If it's a 100% managed library that uses a `FileStream`, you are probably stuck.

If it takes the provided filename and call a native WIN32 `CreateFile` function, it's possible to give it something else than a file such as a named pipe.

To test quickly if it's possible, pass `@"\\.\pipe\random_name"` to the method: if it responds by saying explicitely that it can't open pipes and filenames begining with `\\.\`, well, sorry. ON the other hand, if it says it can't find the file, you have a chance to make it work.

You can then create a `NamedPipeServerStream` and use the same name for your library method call prepended with `\\.\pipe\`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't "represent" it as a file, but you could "convert" it to a file using a `StreamWriter` class.

Comment: I can easily remove MemoryStream and don't even bother with StreamWriter, but i want to keep this file in memory and don't touch the HDD at all.

Comment: I understood what you were asking for, but there is no way to do that.  It does not work that way.

Comment: _If_ the OP wants to save it, `File.SaveAllBytes()` would be much easier and more efficient.

Comment: You can, actually, using some of our products

Comment: @HenkHolterman, I think you mean `File.WriteAllBytes()`... but I'm fairly certain that's just a wrapper for `BinaryWriter.Write()`.